# SparkContext object not getting created

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook and trying to run PySpark commands. I ran the below import commands which ran fine.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

conf=SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('local')
conf.setAppName('spark_basic')
```

Post this, when I am trying to initialize a variable with SparkContext as below, it keeps on running without any error/output:

> sc=SparkContext(conf=conf) #command running without any error/output

Could you please provide any resolution on this issue.

Comment: Instead of sparkContext, have u tried sparkSession using the same conf ? . and try to use logger module in DEBUG mode for checking what's happening when you command in running

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using the below code. Still facing the same issue. 

import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

Comment: have u tried the logger in debug mode and see what was happening ?